# Clear TextField on button press - Java Applet

Tags: java, applet

I have a Java Applet for login form. It has 2 `TextFields`, username and password. I need to clear them on clicking `Reset` button. This is the code I have written.

```
  public class LoginForm extends Applet implements ActionListener
  {
    TextField name, pass, hidden;
    Button b1, b2;

    public void init()
    {
        name = new TextField(20);
        pass = new TextField(20);

        b2 = new Button("Reset");

        add(name);
        add(pass);
        add(b2);

        b2.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString("Hello", 10, 150);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e);

        name.setText("");
        pass.setText("");

        repaint();
    }
  }
```

But this is not working properly.

Once I click the `Reset` button, the `actionPerformed()` method gets called and it also calls `repaint()`. (I can see "Hello" being displayed).

But the TextFields do not get cleared.

---

If I make following changes in `actionPerformed`

```
        name.setText(" ");  // please note the spaces
        pass.setText(" ");
```

then it works. But I don't want spaces there. I want the TextFields to get blank.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: stop using applets. browsers have stopped supporting them years ago

Comment: Of course, I know that. This is a school assignment.

Comment: Please refer the teacher to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). **Note:** I wrote that blog in ***2013,*** somewhat before Oracle finally decided to deprecate & remove the entire Java Plugin used to launch applets. Add to that: Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT components in favor of Swing. Swing replaced AWT long before the problem with applets.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the comment. Actually, I am the **teacher**. I know very well that applets are history. But unfortunately, _I don't set the syllabus, mate_. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it is not good solution, but this is a workaround.Before setting the text invoke `getText` method and it will reset. Pretty strange! This behaviour is marked as Bug on this [page](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8060137)

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    name.getText();
    pass.getText();

    name.setText("");
    pass.setText("");

    repaint();
    revalidate();
}
```

Another solution would be setting text with space. But not if you have password-like fields which have `setEchoChar('*')`.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e);

    name.setText(" ");
    pass.setText(" ");

    repaint();
    revalidate();
}
```

Comment: Well, that was completely unexpected! It works though. If you could give me the reason for this behaviour, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Can't do this, `pass.setText(" ");`, as it shows a `*` in the password field if I have `pass.setEchoChar('*');` on.

Comment: it is marked as BUG on this page https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8060137 check it out. i can not tell you what is a reason.

Comment: I think you should include the BUG link with your answer.

Comment: @linuxartisan i did.

Answer (score 0):

just put blank in text fields.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    name.getText();
    pass.getText();
    name.setText("");
    pass.setText("");
    repaint();
    revalidate();
}
```

Comment: Well, this is the exact same answer as the previous one.